# How do I customize the default master volume setting on a new FL Studio project that I open?

Tags: fl-studio

I want to set the default master volume to 60% every time FL Studio opens up a new project. Is there a way to set this somewhere in the menu options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use templates: Open a new empty project, set the master volume where you want it, and save the project in the templates folder (\Image-Line\FL Studio\Projects\Templates)

Then, in FL Studio, go to Options -> General Settings, change your Default Template to the project you just made, and set your startup project to "Default Template"

Also, if you're doing this, you can customize much more than just the master volume setting.

Here's the official tutorial for making and loading custom templates: https://www.image-line.com/fl-studio-news/custom-templates/